# Understanding PHP's Left Assocative Ternary Operator

Tags: php, operators, associativity

Is there a **documented** explanation/reason why [`PHP`'s ternary operator `? :`](http://php.net/ternary) is left associative rather then right associative. Surely a reason exists for differing the operator from all other imperative languages?

Comment: I don't think you can get an official explanation. Moreover, left-associativity of the ternary operator is by far not the only complaint against PHP, is I don't think there _is_ a good reason. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but I'm afraid answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: PHP is like the human body: grown organically with features grafted on and adopted at random. in other words, it's proof positive against any possible "intelligent design" argument.

Comment: @MarcB I would upvote your comment, except you seem to suggest that humans are provably not a product of intelligent design.

Comment: http://phpsadness.com/sad/30

Comment: @jan: there may be a designer, but looking at the human body proves that there's no intelligence in the design department, and definitely no intelligence in the QA department.

Comment: I wonder if I should dowvnote the question for flamebaiting.

Comment: The word "Documented" is intended illicit references in answers.

Comment: PHP's ternary operator is broken because is broken. That's PHP's motto: "If it's broken, don't fix it"

Comment: @MarcB I would ask for elaboration, but that would be off-topic for this question.

Comment: OK... I admit I had missed the word "documented". I won't downvote, but I'm still afraid answers would be more opinion than facts (but yeah, we can downvote those that are)

Comment: Closevote retracted. Good luck.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Should this be moved to [`Programmers.se`](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If "It was just an oversight" the actual answer, would you acknowledge that as correct?

Comment: @random Yes, if it was documented, and no other documentation was contradictory or more explanatory.